# Sorry, we couldn't open your file using this feature. Visio Web Access is not available on this site.

Tags: 2013, web, visio

Recently installed Service Pack 1 in SharePoint Server 2013 Farm, post upgrade we are experiencing issue when opening visio documents:

I am trying to open .vsdx (visio 2013) file but encounter following issue:

Sorry, we couldn't open your file using this feature. Visio Web Access is not available on this site.[image]

Under Document library-->Library settings-->Advanced Settings

[image]

Still I cant open file in browser as we always used to. Unfortunately we don't have Visio services in Farm.

can you share your experiences regarding this issue post Sp1 SharePoint Server 2013.

Thank You

Comment: Is this migrated site? what is web app's general settings browser handling settings? try with use the default....

Comment: it is a migrated site using 3rd party utility. but until Sp1 was upgraded we were not experiencing the issue. we originally had default option, but we had same issue.